# How to use project which is already in VSS?

Tags: c#, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to add my project under source control. I am using "Microsoft VSS 6.0" for it. My problem is, there is one project in VSS which I had copied on my system using 'Get Latest Version' to C:\latest_version directory. Then I copied that entire project in other directory (C:\working) and deleted the directory where I had taken latest version of it (C:\latest_version).
   Now everytime I make any changes in code and want to do check in, I need to check out that particular file in some folder, copy-replace that file with my new file and check-in.
   Can we do all this through visual studio? I saw some tutorials which describe how to add project to VSS but in my case project is already is in VSS and I just want to link it with my project. Is it possible?
   I dont know whether I am using VSS correctly or not. I would like to know how do people usually use it? How to do check-in , check-out?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If you have a choice, stop using VSS and pick up one of the open source version control tools (Mecurial, Git, and Subversion to name three). They're more reliable (VSS is prone to corruption) and there are lots of good tutorials out there. Here is a good one for Mecurial: http://hginit.com/

Comment: Thanks Bevan, but I cannot move to other version control systems.

Comment: Oh dear ... you should bookmark this (you'll need it): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/133054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the working directory in VSS to point to your new directory.

Comment: ok. After changing working directory can I do check-in/out from visual studio?

Comment: Try opening the project from source control (there is an option in Visual Studio).

Comment: Thaks a lot . I got the option. I was looking for exaactly this thing but was unable to find it.  Thanks again !!! Although I visual studio is giving me error while opening project something like 'this project was not added to VSS using visual studio and you need to change source control....' I will figure out how to solve this new problem.
Thanks once again.